# Store timestamp in format 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS:MS' in Postgres DB

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, datetime, .net-core

I want to store date & time in my Db in format `DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS:MS`. E.g, `15/10/2022 22:42:43:682`.

But it is actually stored in DB as `Oct 15 22:42:43`.
I couldn't find any relative info except for `to_char` method which actually converts date & time to string. But I want to store in date & time format.

What is the right way to this?

Respective DB column type is `timestamp`. And I gave timezone when creating tables.

Comment: Date and time related data types in databases are stored as _binary_. They may be _displayed_ in a different format based on your computer's culture. Data storage and data presentation are very different things. Also, what does "And i gave timezone when creating tables." mean?

Comment: I have no experience in Postgresql, but with most databases, a colum type of `timestamp` means that the data represents a date/time quantity using an internal format. It's very unlikely that it stores it as a string. What you are likely seeing is the Timestamp being rendered as a string using a default format

Comment: "*But i want to store in date & time format.*" - no you don't. You want to _display_ the value in a different format, and that's precisely what `to_char()` will help you do

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out in the comments date/times are stored in binary format, not as a formatted string. The formatting you see comes from the settings in whatever client you are using. That is where the change to the format needs to occur. As an example using the Postgres command line client [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html):

```
show datestyle ;

 DateStyle 
-----------
 SQL, MDY
 
select now();
              now               
--------------------------------
 10/16/2022 09:07:16.987763 PDT


-- The format you want to change from.
set datestyle = 'postgres, mdy';

select now();
                 now                 
-------------------------------------
 Sun Oct 16 09:07:47.820043 2022 PDT

-- The format you want to change to.
set datestyle = 'sql, dmy';

select now();
              now               
--------------------------------
 16/10/2022 09:08:12.556156 PDT
```

For more information on `DateStyle` see [Datetime](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) *8.5.2. Date/Time Output* and the `postgresql.conf` setting [DateStyle setting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE). The import part to remember is that this just affects the display formatting, it does not change how the value is stored. This also means any other client may display the value in it's own format. Generally I find the format of the value is not important until you get to the part where you display it to the end user.